# What is the optimal structure for Gateways and Adapters in Clean Architecture?

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, tdd, adapter, clean-architecture

I'm embarking on a project using Clean Architecture, TypeScript, and TDD. One of my primary concerns is structuring the gateways and adapters correctly, particularly database adapters.

There's some advice circulating around suggesting to avoid classes due to the overhead and resource usage. With this assumption in mind, I've explored two different methods for structuring gateways and adapters:

- Approach 1: Define gateways as interfaces, with adapters being the implementations of these interfaces.
- Approach 2: Define gateways as higher-order functions (functions that return functions), accepting adapters as arguments.

In this [repository](https://github.com/fabrizionastri/clean-architecture-mini-demo), I've made a simple implementation of these approaches.

The first approach appears to be safer, providing a clear contract for the adapters and is, arguably, more straightforward. On the other hand, the second approach provides more flexibility by enabling logic to be inserted into the gateways, albeit at the cost of reduced safety and increased complexity.

I'm interested in the community's thoughts and advice on these approaches. Which approach is recommended, and why? Can anyone provide some examples or feedback on the structure I've set up in my repository?

Below are some code snippets from the repository for reference:

Gateways:

```
interface OrderGateway1 {
  getAll: () => Promise<Order[] | undefined>
  getById: (orderId: string) => Promise<Order | undefined>
}

const orderGateway2 = (orderDbAdapter: any) => {
  return {
    getAll: (): Order[] => orderDbAdapter.getAll(),
    getById: (orderId: string): Order => orderDbAdapter.getById(orderId),
  }
}
```

In-memory Data Storage Adapters:

```
const orderInMemoryDbAdapter1: OrderGateway1 = (() => {
  const ordersDb: Order[] = [...inMemoryDb.orders]
  return {
    getAll: () => Promise.resolve(ordersDb),
    getById: (orderId: string) => Promise.resolve(ordersDb.find((order) => order.id === orderId)),
  }
})()


const orderInMemoryDbAdapter2 = () => {
  const ordersDb: Order[] = [...inMemoryDb.orders]
  return {
    getAll: () => ordersDb,
    getById: (orderId: string) => ordersDb.find((order) => order.id === orderId),
  }
}
```

JSON Server Data Storage Adapters:

```
const orderJsonServerDbAdapter1: OrderGateway1 = {
  getAll: async (): Promise<Order[] | undefined> => {
    const result = await api.get<Order[]>('/orders')
    return result
  },
  getById: async (id: string): Promise<Order | undefined> => {
    const result = await api.get<Order>(`/orders/${id}`)
    return result
  },
}

const orderJsonServerDbAdapter2 = () => {
  return {
    getAll: async (): Promise<Order[] | undefined> => {
      const result = await api.get<Order[]>('/orders')
      return result
    },
    getById: async (id: string): Promise<Order | undefined> => {
      const result = await api.get<Order>(`/orders/${id}`)
      return result
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go either way, but the second aproach is not a higher-order function. Since the function you define does not return another function. It returns an object that has multiple functions.

```
const orderGateway2 = (orderDbAdapter: any) => {
  return {
    getAll: (): Order[] => orderDbAdapter.getAll(),
    getById: (orderId: string): Order => orderDbAdapter.getById(orderId),
  }
}
```

The important thing is to comply with the architecture rules. So adapters should have dependencies to use cases not use cases to adapters. As a result the use case must define the interface it needs and the adapter implements it.

I took a look at your repository and saw the definition of your use case. Your use case construction function defines the gateway as type `any`.

```
export const fetchOrderById = (gateway: any) => (orderId: string) => {
  return gateway.getById(orderId)
}
```

You should put the gateway interface declaration in the same module, since the use case needs it. E.g.

```
export interface OrderGateway {
  getAll: () => Promise<Order[] | undefined>
  getById: (orderId: string) => Promise<Order | undefined>
}

export const fetchOrderById = (gateway:OrderGateway) => (orderId: string) => {
  return gateway.getById(orderId)
}
```

The adapters can then import the `OrderGateway`. I would also use the same name for the `OrderGatway` in both adapter modules (inMemory and jsonServer).

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse, Method } from 'axios'
import { Order } from 'entities/order'

import { OrderGateway } from 'src/core/usecases/fetchById'

// ...
export const orderGateway: OrderGateway = {
  getAll: async (): Promise<Order[] | undefined> => {
    const result = await api.get<Order[]>('/orders')
    return result
  },
  getById: async (id: string): Promise<Order | undefined> => {
    const result = await api.get<Order>(`/orders/${id}`)
    return result
  },
}
```

If you give them the same name it is just a path replacement of the import to switch between them:

```
 import { orderGateway } from 'adapters/jsonServer/orderJsonServerDbAdapter'

 // import { orderGateway } from 'adapters/inMemory/orderInMemoryDBAdapter'

 import { fetchOrderById } from 'core/usecases/fetchById'

 const fetchOrderByIdUseCase = fetchOrderById(orderGateway)
```

Comment: Thanks @RenéLink. Yes indeed, we should used interfaces for both Gateways and Adapters in all cases to define the contract that the use case expects. The real difference between approach 1 and 2 is not wether to use interfaces (we should in all cases), but whether to only use adapters (approach 1) or to use both gateways and adapters (approach 2).
The benefit of approach 1 is simplicity (only 1 object to code and test).
The benefits of approach 2 is that you can move some logic out of the adapter and into the gateway, thus simplifying your adapters. I will update my repo accordingly.